# Wordpress: Where is data being saved?

Tags: wordpress

I've installed Wordpress, with the Boss theme, and got all the demos. Using the Forum demo, I added a topic; it then displayed the topic I added on the screen. Where is this data being saved? Someone said to check the MySQL table, wp-posts, but it's not in there, nor anywhere else I can see.

I need to modifiy this Forum page, so understanding where the data is being saved would definitely help. Does anyone know how Forum data is saved?

Comment: Try in settings table

Answer (score 0):

The Boss theme works with the plugins BuddyPress and bbPress.
If the data you are talking about belongs to bbPress (forums) it should definitely be located in the wp_posts table with a "forum" or "topic" post_type (table column).

If the data is related to the user's profile/activity stream, you should check the wp_bp_activity table.

Also, if you have access to a phpMyAdmin in your hosting, [you could do a global search in all tables](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/phpmyadmin/searching-through-a-mysql-database-in-phpmyadmin) and find that content more easily.

Comment: Thanks! It was in wp-posts after all. Any chance you know where the code is that does the saving and retrieving? When I copied the Forum demo page and tried to keep just the functioning code, it would not save the new topic I created. Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you found it. Not sure about the code you are looking for, I don't own the theme, but you could use some hooks that allow you to modify the content of topics/replies before these are saved (bbp_new_topic_handler/bbp_new_reply_handler) and some other hooks to change the content when retrieving (bbp_get_topic_content/bbp_get_reply_content).